# How to subtract quantity in one form from main quantity in another form in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019

I have two forms in my vb.net project, one is Medform where I add my Medicine name, Quantity, Medicine Price, Manufacturing and expiry dates and another form known as Billing form where I sell the drugs, so each time I sell a drug on the billing form, I want the Available quantity or stock to be subtracted from the current quantity sold and display in the billing form label called available stock, and to be also automatically subtracted from the main quantity in the medform. Both forms have different database tables.
Below is the code for the Medform Add button

```
  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
    Try

        If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            conn.Open()
        End If
        Using create As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblMed([Med_ID], [MedName], [MedPrice], [MedQuantity], [MfgDate], [ExpDate], [Company])VALUES(@Med_ID, @MedName, @MedPrice, @MedQuantity, @MfgDate, @ExpDate, @Company)", conn)
            create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Med_ID", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Med_ID_TextBox.Text.Trim
            create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = MedNameTextBox.Text.Trim
            create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedPrice", OleDbType.Currency).Value = MedPriceTextBox.Text
            create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MedQuantity", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = MedQtyTextBox.Text.Trim
            create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MfgDate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = MfgDate.Text.Trim
            create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpDate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ExpDate.Text.Trim
            create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = CompCb.SelectedValue.ToString()




            If create.ExecuteNonQuery Then
                Med_ID_TextBox.Clear()
                MedNameTextBox.Clear()
                MedPriceTextBox.Clear()
                MedQtyTextBox.Clear()

                bind_data()
            End If


        End Using

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try


End Sub
```

And below are the codes for the Billing Form Add to Bill Button

```
Private Sub btnBill_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBill.Click


    Try

        If txtQty.Text > stock Then
            MsgBox("Not Enough in Stock")
        ElseIf txtQty.Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Enter a quantity")
        Else

            'Let's Add Medicine To The Bill
            Dim rnum As Integer = BillGridView.Rows.Add()
            i = i + 1
            BillGridView.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Column1").Value = i
            BillGridView.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Column2").Value = MediComboCb.SelectedValue.ToString()
            BillGridView.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Column3").Value = txtQty.Text
            BillGridView.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Column4").Value = AgentNameCb.Text
            BillGridView.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Column5").Value = txtBillDate.Text
            BillGridView.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Column6").Value = MedPrice
            BillGridView.Rows.Item(rnum).Cells("Column7").Value = txtQty.Text * MedPrice + GrTot



            Dim subtotal = txtQty.Text * MedPrice

            GrTot = GrTot + subtotal
            TotalAmountlb.Text = GrTot

            If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                con.Open()
            End If

            Using create As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO tblBill([AgentName], [DrugName], [Quantity], [BillDate], [UnitPrice], [TotalAmount])VALUES(@AgentName, @DrugName, @Quantity, @BillDate, @UnitPrice, TotalAmount)", con)
                create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AgentName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = AgentNameCb.Text.Trim
                create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DrugName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = MediComboCb.SelectedValue.ToString()
                create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Quantity", OleDbType.Integer).Value = txtQty.Text.Trim
                create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BillDate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = txtBillDate.Text.Trim
                create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UnitPrice", OleDbType.Currency).Value = MedPrice
                create.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalAmount", OleDbType.Currency).Value = TotalAmountlb.Text



                If create.ExecuteNonQuery Then
                    txtQty.Clear()
                    AgentNameCb.Text = ""

                End If

            End Using


        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be to run a timer that queries the database every few seconds and refreshes your labels.

A much better approach would be to create a class in which you load the drug data from the database:

```
Public Class Drug

    Private _quantity As Integer

    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property BillDate As DateTime
    Public Property UnitPrice As Single

    Public Event QuantityChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Public Property Quantity As Integer
        Get
            Return _quantity
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If value <> _quantity Then
                _quantity = value
                RaiseEvent QuantityChanged(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
            End If
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

You create instances of this class for all the drugs in your database and add these instances into a List(Of Drug) (see [List Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-5.0)). Then, you pass this List to both Forms so they work on the same data.

In your class, you can detect changes and raise events to:

1. Notify your forms that the data has changed and update your labels.
2. Update the database with the new data.